# Remove sinlge new lines

Tags: javascript, regex, newline

I want to replace single new lines with one space like if I have string like this:

```
"foo\nbar\nbaz\n\nquux"
```

I want to have

```
"foo bar baz\n\nquux"
```

I've tried this regex: `/\n(?!\n)/` but it don't work it replace single new line by space but also one new line that have new line after.

Comment: @ochi how does that work? All that does is match two new lines.

Comment: @ochi this will match two newlines and I want to match one.

Comment: sorry misread the question, removed comment

Comment: @iismathwizard I don't want to match all new lines only single new line with no new line after.

Comment: @jcubic i *also* misread the question. My apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
"foo\nbar\nbaz\n\nquux".replace(/([^\n])\n(?!\n)/g,"$1 ")
```

Your original was skipping the first `\n` in the pair, and then replacing the second (because it's not followed by a `\n`). You need to check it doesn't have a `\n` after *or before* it. The `$1` puts the matched non-newline character back in. Unfortunately, javascript doesn't support non-consuming look-behinds.

Answer (score 1):

```
(^|(?!\n).)\n(?!\n)
```

Another variant of [@Matt's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34774733/3679490) answer.See demo.Replace by `$1`

https://regex101.com/r/iJ7bT6/7